# Numerical Fredholm integration using loop

Tags: conditional, procedural-programming

I have a code line having two `Do` loops, one within other. In certain situation arising within inner loop, I want the outer `Do` loop to break. How to achieve it ?

Here is a simplified example.

```
X = {{-10, 1, 1}, { 8, 2, 2},  {-7, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 2}};
XX = Reap[
   Do[Do[If[X[[k, 1]] < 0, R = m*X[[k, 2]]; Sow[R], R = m*X[[k, 3]]; 
      Sow[R]], {k, 1, 4}], {m, 1, 5}]][[2]]
```

The o/p of this code is

```
{{1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 6, 9, 6, 4, 8, 12, 8, 5, 10, 15, 10}}
```

Now for example, the element "9" appears in the o/p for the m = 3 cycle. I want to break the m loop for the next value of m as soon as "9" appears in the o/p. So in this case, the m cycle should stop at m = 3 instead of going up to 5. The o/p in that case should be

{{`1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 6, 9, 6}}`

I tried the beard combination of Break & Catch/Throw as shown below, but not able to make it work.

```
    X = {{-10, 1, 1}, { 8, 2, 2},  {-7, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 2}};
XX = Reap[
       Do[Catch[
         Do[If[X[[k, 1]] < 0, R = m*X[[k, 2]]; Sow[R]; 
           If[R == 9, Throw[Break[]]], R = m*X[[k, 3]];
           Sow[R]]; If[R == 9, Throw[Break[]]], {k, 1, 4}]], {m, 1, 
         5}]][[2]]
```

Will appreciate any help.

thanks

Comment: See [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return.html). If that does not do what is required, post a minimal working example and explain what exactly you want.

Comment: In this case you can also use multiple iterators in `Do` since the number of inner loops doesn't depend on the outer loop. Then anything (`Break[]`, `Return[..., Do]`, `Throw/Catch`) will work.

Comment: "Break" is not working for sure as it breaks the inner loop, not the outer. Catch/Throw looks promising, but perhaps I am not able to use it properly. I have added the code line in the original question, will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: `Throw[Break[]]` is a strange construct. What should it achieve? Why don't you use `Throw` with a normal argument?

Comment: What does "o/p" mean? What does "break the loop" mean for you?

Comment: I want m cycle to end as soon as one of the elements is 9, which happens under m = 3. I want the m loop to stop there, not continuing for m = 3, 4.

Comment: And what does "o/p" mean?

Comment: Please read my original post, it explains !!

Answer (score 4):

[`Throw`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Throw.html)/[`Catch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catch.html) would probably work:

```
Catch[
  Do[
    Do[Print[{i, j}];
       If[j == 7, Throw[7]],
    {j, 10}],
  {i, 10}]]

(*    {1,1}    *)
(*    {1,2}    *)
(*    {1,3}    *)
(*    {1,4}    *)
(*    {1,5}    *)
(*    {1,6}    *)
(*    {1,7}    *)

(*    7    *)
```

The advantage of [`Throw`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Throw.html) over [`Break`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Break.html) is that the latter quits only the innermost loop, whereas for the former you can decide how many loops to quit by setting the [`Catch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catch.html) appropriately.

**Update:** you seem to want to break only the outer loop but let the inner one finish the current iteration. This could work:

```
X = {{-10, 1, 1}, {8, 2, 2}, {-7, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 2}};
stop = False;
XX = Reap[Do[Do[If[X[[k, 1]] < 0, R = m*X[[k, 2]]; Sow[R];
                If[R == 9, stop = True], R = m*X[[k, 3]];
                Sow[R]]; If[R == 9, stop = True], {k, 1, 4}];
             If[stop, Break[]], {m, 1, 5}]][[2, 1]]
(*    {1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 6, 9, 6}    *)
```

The trick here is to set a flag `stop` in the inner loop, and at the end of the inner loop check this flag and conditionally break the outer loop.